# How to log information in Forge?

Tags: java, logging, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to log into using MinecraftServer.logInfo(), but I get a nosuchmethod exception.

```
    server.logInfo("Example message");
```

I'm getting the instance of MinecraftServer in the server starting event.

```
    MinecraftServer server = event.getServer();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a simple

```
System.out.println("Information!");
```

Should do in forge.

Answer (score 11):

An option for a fully fledged logger is

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(YourMod.MODID);
```

Comment: This is a better alternative to the suggested preInit code `event.getModLog()`, as some things apparently run before preInit and still need to be logged.  This can be set right where it's declared as `public static final Logger` in the main class and it's wonderful, works like a charm.  You just have to remember to `import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`  and `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;`